# COLMAP camera pose estimation issue

Tags: 3d-reconstruction, pose, colmap

I was working with COLMAP to find camera poses on custom images. The images also have mask images. When I am using the COLMAP CLI, the commands are not executing and CMD is skipping the commands. In the COLMAP GUI, it is showing "No good initial image pair found". Can anyone suggest how to resolve this issue?

COLMAP GUI ON RECONSTRUCTION OF CUSTOM IMAGES

[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC8VH.png)]

I tried Camera pose estimation of custom images in COLMAP , firstly i tried with CLI and failed to execute on that and started working with COLMAP GUI and struck with an "No good initial image pair found" while reconstruction

I was expecting camera poses for my custom images